# Windows Phone - communication with background agent

Tags: windows-phone, mutex, background-agent

i somehow need to communicate between my background agent and my main application.

I have read things about mutex and IsolatedStorage, and it can be achieved with a database i heared.

I have never worked with a database or mutex before, could someone provide a link with detail explanation on this topic?

I could't find anything useful on this topic.

Thanks

Comment: Windows Phone 7 or 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good sample that uses IPC at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-named-events-for-IPC-133e5bf9. It includes native code for some of the wiring but should be pretty much usable as is.